# Any way to keep Windows 7 (Ultimate) from deleting the thumbnail cache?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails

First order of business: Drag OP long and hard for using an OS that's way past EOL. Now that we got that out of the way...

It seems that Windows 7 is deleting my thumbnail cache at some arbitrary interval or event. All I know is that opening my pictures folders every day results in severe hard drive thrashing as Windows rebuilds the cache. Many of these are very large images like 6mb PNGs which take extra time to create thumbnails from.

Anything I can do to have Windows stop rebuilding it? Perhaps set a size limit or something so that I can let grow well into the gigs if I want? Or perhaps something in my system is broken. Any way for me to diagnose what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, thumbnail cache is deleted periodically (every several days).

You can choose to Deny deletion which should then keep your thumbnails.

For each User (there may be just you) you need go to the folder where the thumbnails are.

Nominally, users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer

Then go to the Properties of the folder, Security, Advanced, change permissions.

Drill down to get to the property:  Delete Subfolders and Files and choose  DENY.

Apply this setting and OK out.  You need to do this for all Users if more than you and if there are more folders for thumbnails.

Here is a reference for you.

[Deny thumbnail file deletion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-prevent-windows-7-from-deleting-the/f6733775-ad15-4231-944a-8d6f23c94df8)

There are some settings which need to be changed, which will stop deleting the thumbnails.

Follow the steps below:

Right click on the folder which maintains the Thumbnails cache, here:

> 1. Users{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" (where {username} is replaced by the name of the windows user)
> 2. Click Properties
> 3. Click Security
> 4. Click Advanced
> 5. Click change permissions
> 6. Listed are all the users who are allowed to use this folder (I have "System", "Administrator" and my user "Neil". For each user:
> 7. Click Edit
> 8. Under the "Apply to" drop down list, select: this folder and files
> 9. Check the box under deny for: Delete, Delete Subfolders and Files
>    and Take Ownership.  The Take Ownership part is the most important.
>    Without denying Take Ownership, the first two lines will not make any
>    difference.  The cache will still be deleted.  Most websites do not
>    mention this.  I found this out from my own trial and error.
> 10. Click OK

Good luck - this should work for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I just made the change for SYSTEM and will see how it performs. If it works, I'll mark yours as answer.

Comment: Been trying a few variations of this for a couple days and it doesn't appear to be working. I've revoked file/subfolder delete permissions on the folder for SYSTEM and Administrators and the thumbnails are still be regenerated after every reboot.

Comment: I will keep looking around. Denying deletion of Files and Folders is the only way I have seen so far.

Comment: Many thanks, but I've searched far and wide and the only other solution was this massive 15-step hack that wasn't worth it in the end. If you find anything, would like to see it, but I am fine waiting to see if anyone else comes up with anything, so it's all good. Thanks again.